# how to get facebook access token from return url

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

After authencating through my FB application I am getting access token in redirect url as below -

```
128.136.227.197/readjson.php#access_token=CAACYyELn7nsBANisLtwVsjibKZC3JSZButoKyO3GC9aPOTXtrWOtEV0lcIMnXGSVPWZCngewl2MtinU9FsJ9hnWdV1yQDVsUFZAZAYsosEVtKwZCR5HBtdAd7CQrsvprUKlDOZALBWmbmhy4HkvW8GCsx9OkwZDZD&expires_in=4527
```

How to get this accesstoken in my php script ?

I am trying to get it like below -

```
if($_REQUEST['access_token'])
echo $access_token=$_REQUEST['access_token'];
```

But not getting it's value.

Please help me to get access_token in my script readjson.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to parse the URL with the access token in it, you can simply strip away anything but the access token

A simple call to `preg_match()` does the trick

```
$str = "128.136.227.197/readjson.php#access_token=CAACYyELn7nsBANisLtwVsjibKZC3JSZButoKyO3GC9aPOTXtrWOtEV0lcIMnXGSVPWZCngewl    2MtinU9FsJ9hnWdV1yQDVsUFZAZAYsosEVtKwZCR5HBtdAd7CQrsvprUKlDOZALBWmbmhy4HkvW8GCsx9OkwZDZD&expires_in=4527";

preg_match("/access_token=(.*)(?=&)/", $str, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
echo "</pre>";
```

The above prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => access_token=CAACYyELn7nsBANisLtwVsjibKZC3JSZButoKyO3GC9aPOTXtrWOtEV0lcIMnXGSVPWZCngewl2MtinU9FsJ9hnWdV1yQDVsUFZAZAYsosEVtKwZCR5HBtdAd7CQrsvprUKlDOZALBWmbmhy4HkvW8GCsx9OkwZDZD
    [1] => CAACYyELn7nsBANisLtwVsjibKZC3JSZButoKyO3GC9aPOTXtrWOtEV0lcIMnXGSVPWZCngewl2MtinU9FsJ9hnWdV1yQDVsUFZAZAYsosEVtKwZCR5HBtdAd7CQrsvprUKlDOZALBWmbmhy4HkvW8GCsx9OkwZDZD
)
```

Comment: Thanks. but how to get this url in code ? I am trying with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but it gives me only 128.136.227.197/readjson.php not access token

Comment: The browser doesn't actually send anything that comes after the `#` to the server as it's resolved browser side. You can, however, use JavaScript's `document.location.hash`, and pass it to the server with an Ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is passed as URI Fragment, it will not be accessible using `$_REQUEST` There are two ways which I am aware of. One is using Javascript(which i am not familiar with) and the other using PHP.

```
$url=parse_url("http://128.136.227.197/readjson.php#access_token=CAACYyELn7nsBANisLtwVsjibKZC3JSZButoKyO3GC9aPOTXtrWOtEV0lcIMnXGSVPWZCngewl2MtinU9FsJ9hnWdV1yQDVsUFZAZAYsosEVtKwZCR5HBtdAd7CQrsvprUKlDOZALBWmbmhy4HkvW8GCsx9OkwZDZD&expires_in=4527");

$fragment = $url['fragment'];

$access_token = preg_replace('/&expires_in=(.*)/',"",$fragment); //To obtain access_token part only
```

P.S The above code is tested only for the given url.

Answer (score 0):

You are using client side without JS SDK authentication for a server side implementation.

**Don't do that.**

The correct way would be to use a server side authentication flow which allows the code/token to be obtained in `$_REQUEST`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

Answer (score 0):

It seem the only way is via Javascript w/ Ajax, as the browser does not pass the URL fragment to the server. So with javascript you can pass either the full URL w/ the fragment to the server (via ajax or a redirect with the URL in the GET query) and parse the URL w/

```
    parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```

Or you can parse the fragment in javascript and pass the information via GET or POST to the server in an ajax call.